# How to create new Partitions without creating a new collection?

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb

I'm trying to create a new Partitions inside of a collection without creating a new Collection?

I already created a new collection with a new partionkey, but now I'm trying to create some inside of a collection.

```
DocumentCollection collectionDefinition = new DocumentCollection();
collectionDefinition.Id = collectionId;
collectionDefinition.PartitionKey.Paths.Add("/IoTDevices"); //--> add this

DocumentCollection partitionedCollection = await client.CreateDocumentCollectionAsync(
    UriFactory.CreateDatabaseUri(databaseId),
    collectionDefinition,
    new RequestOptions { OfferThroughput = 10100 });
```

Answer (score 0):

you dont need to create partitions inside collections. when you create a document inside the collection it will get assigned to an appropriate partition automatically based on partition key value of the document you are creating. if the partition doesn't exist - it will get created.